# electronjs and node server communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, electron

I have a node server and i have an elektron desktop app (electronjs).they are in the same machine. I need to comminicate each other.

> But i need to do this in main process  i dont want to use renderer
>   processes.In my Case my renderer process can only talk with main.

Fistly, i thought that I can Create an API ,so node server  send http request and i can get request then i will do my jobs in electron. But I coundt find any way to do this.

Secondly, i thought that I can use socket.io and send to json data(in main proccess) and again i couldnt find any way.

One of them is enough for me. I searched but i coudnt find a way to do this. Is there a Single code example or a link or an explanation.. Thanks.

Comment: if you can see the node server from a browser on the machine, you should be able to use ajax to talk to it from the app. if the server needs to reach out to the app, the app will need to keep a connection going, or host it's own wen server on a different port, or use socket.io on both the app and server.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Did you mean can i use ajax in main renderer? And if i use socket.io how can comminicate.Is there any single example which is sending json from node and get data in main renderer in electron app

Comment: If it's an electron app where you're communicating between the browser and the node process, have you looked at `ipc`? http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.7/api/ipc-main/ http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.7/api/ipc-renderer/